# Acrobat Javascript Save & Exit Button

Tags: javascript, api, pdf, acrobat

I have a writeable pdf form created in acrobat pro. Now, i added a button which has to change a fields value, save the pdf and close it.

I decided to do this as following:

```
var fieldX = this.getField("xxxxField");
fieldX.value = 1;
app.execMenuItem("Save");
this.closeDoc(true);
```

But this doesn't save the pdf.

I don't want to have a confirmation dialog. I saw the `saveAs` function in the API but how to get the real-path incl. filename of the current editing document? Or do you have any other approaches?

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But this doesn't save the pdf.

That's because there are security restrictions that prevent `app.execMenuItem("Save");` from working. You're not allowed to call Save via JS.

> function in the API but how to get the real-path incl. filename of the current editing document? Or do you have any other approaches?

You can use `Doc.path` to get the path of the current document including its filename (and `Doc.documentFilename` gives you the filename only).

However, `saveAs` is also subject to security restrictions, and it can only be called in a "privileged" context (batch or console). So this won't work either.

In short, security restrictions will prevent you from saving documents without asking the user. If you think about it, it's only logical.

See: [Acrobat JS API Reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Client side code to save PDF Data used below link or code. It's Client side trusted function which you need to put in `C:\Program Files\Adobe\...\JavaScript\Config.js.`

[How to Save a PDF with Acrobat JavaScript](https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/how-save-pdf-acrobat-javascript)

1) Code to save data at folder level.

```
var mySaveAs = app.trustedFunction ( function(oDoc,cPath,cFlName)
{

app.beginPriv();
    var flag=false; 

    cPath = cPath.replace(/([^\/])$/, "$1/");

    if(cPath.indexOf("http://") !== -1 || cPath.indexOf("https://") !== -1)
    {
        cPath = cPath.replace('http://', "\\\\");
        cPath = cPath.replace('https://', "\\\\");

        while(cPath.indexOf("/") !== -1)
        {
            cPath = cPath.replace('/', "\\\\");          
        }
    }

    if(cPath.indexOf(":") !== -1)
    {       
        cPath = cPath.replace(":","@"); 
    }


    try{

        oDoc.saveAs(cPath + cFlName);        

        flag = true;

    }catch(e){
        app.alert("Error During Save");
    }
    app.endPriv();

    return flag;
});
```

2) Code to save data at SharePoint.

```
var mySaveAs = app.trustedFunction ( function(oDoc,cPath,cFlName)
{

    app.beginPriv();
    var flag=false;
    try{                         
        app.execMenuItem("Save");        
        flag = true;         
    }catch(e){
        app.alert("Error During Save");
    }
    app.endPriv();  
    return flag;
});
```