# How to write a text file in Acrobat Javascript

Tags: javascript, text, acrobat

I am using acrobat XI
I have tried output a text file like this

```
var cMyC = "abc";
var doc = this.createDataObject({cName: "test.txt", cValue: cMyC});
this.exportDataObject({cName: "test.txt", nLaunch:0});
```

This is working , but I would like to provided a fixed path and no dialog is popup to request the user choose a saving path

Are there any way to fix the problem? thanks

Answer (score 7):

All Acrobat JavaScript functions that write a file to the user’s local disk pose a security risk, so there are some restrictions placed on their use. These functions include `doc.saveAs()` and all of the data export functions, like `doc.exportAsFDF()`.
As you can read [here](http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/file-paths-acrobat-javascript):

> Acrobat provides us with two modes of operation for these
>   functions--with a path and without a path. If no path parameter is
>   provided to the function, Acrobat displays a file-browser dialog. The
>   file browser dialog gives users control over how data is saved to
>   their systems. If a path is provided to the function, then no dialog
>   is displayed and the operation is handled silently, i.e., the user is
>   not necessarily aware that data has been saved to their hard drive.
>   This is a security problem, so to use one of these functions in silent
>   mode, the function must be executed from a privileged context. This
>   means the code must reside in a trusted location. For example, code
>   executed from the Console Window, a Batch Process or a certified PDF
>   is privileged. When any of these functions are used with a path
>   parameter and executed in a non-privileged context, Acrobat will throw
>   an exception. The reasoning behind this restriction is, if the code
>   can’t be trusted, then the user has to specifically select the file
>   location.
>
> Another restriction on saving data to the user’s system is that the
>   path specification must be a Safe Path. A safe path is one that
>   doesn’t point to a restricted location on the user’s hard drive or one
>   that might pose a security risk. Examples of these restricted
>   locations are the system folder and the root folder of any hard drive.
>   Other folders that might be restricted are dependent on the operating
>   system and the sensibilities of the Acrobat developers. Neither is
>   well documented, so it’s best to use these functions carefully.

About "Safe Paths", the Acrobat JS API `doc.saveAS` [method documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat10_SDK_HTMLHelp&file=JS_API_AcroJS.88.519.html) states:

> Acrobat 6.0 introduced the concept of a safe path for JavaScript
>   methods that write data to the local hard drive based on a path passed
>   to it by one of its parameters. A path cannot point to a system
>   critical folder, for example a root, windows or system directory. A
>   path is also subject to other unspecified tests. For many methods, the
>   file name must have an extension appropriate to the type of data that
>   is to be saved. Some methods may have a no-overwrite restriction.
>   These additional restrictions are noted in the documentation.
>   Generally, when a path is judged to be not safe, a NotAllowedError
>   exception is thrown (see Error object) and the method fails.

For sure you can't do it with the `exportDataObject` method, since it has no `path` parameter, as you can also read [here](http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/print/importing-and-exporting-pdf-file-attachments-acrobat-javascript):

> The "cName" parameter is a required input and specifies the specific
>   file attachment that will be exported. Notice there is no path
>   parameter. There is in fact a "cPath" input to this function, but it
>   is no longer valid. If you try to use a path in this function, it will
>   fail and throw an exception. It doesn't matter what context the
>   function is called from because the "cPath" parameter was removed from
>   all usage.

Further references:

- [Write Text file using Acrobat Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760440/write-text-file-using-acrobat-javascript)
- [Acrobat Javascript Save and Exit Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221743/acrobat-javascript-save-exit-button)

Comment: Thanks for providing information! I have tried using Doc.exportAsText but it simply not working . 

To be precise : 1) How to create an text object, how to write it to the text file? thanks

Comment: I have alredy tried create report, create data object but none of them can be saved to a text file.....

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to output to a fixed path text file using `doc.exportAsText`:

```
// set up output text
var TEMP_FIELD_NAME = "testHeader"
var textValue = "test";
// add a temporary text field
var f = this.addField(TEMP_FIELD_NAME, "text", 0, [30,30,100,20]);
f.value = textValue;
// export field name and value to defined file
this.exportAsText({aFields: TEMP_FIELD_NAME, cPath: "test-text.txt"});
// remove text field
this.removeField(TEMP_FIELD_NAME);
```

The resulting text file will have two lines:

testHeader

test

Answer (score 3):

Impossible. For security reasons, saving a file automatically is not allowed.

As stated in the SDK:

```
Beginning with Acrobat 6.0, if the parameter cDIPath is non-null, a NotAllowedError  exception is thrown and the method fails.
If cDIPath is not passed to this method, a file selection dialog box opens to allow the user to select a save path for the embedded data object.
```