# Is there any way in Javascript (node) or Python to extract just the form data of a PDF and convert it to JSON?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I've got a PDF made with Jotform which has fillable fields. Is there some easy way to extract just the data from those fields? I've looked around github but I haven't found a tool that can do that that is specifically for form data.

Do fillable PDF files have some easily extractable format that gives a key and a value for the form?

As a bonus, I'd like to also be able to write to that form as well.

My use case is going through a lot of fillable pdf's which are the same PDF but different values filled into the forms. I want to build a tool to display a single field value from all of the forms combined and then I can edit those form fields.

Comment: Duplicate: [Extract PDF Form Data Using JavaScript and write to CSV File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579408/extract-pdf-form-data-using-javascript-and-write-to-csv-file)

Comment: PDF ISO format defines XFDF, which is XML format that stores the key/value pairs you want. You could then use whatever pattern you like to convert from XML to JSON.

Comment: @Ouroborus that post doesn't answer my question. I don't want to have the pdf run any JavaScript inside of it. I want to get node to extract the data.